# Parameter being set to null using Google test on C++ while Type Parameterizing the test class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, googletest

I am using Google test in C++ in Visual Studio. I have two Types, Type1 and Type2 and have a class, MyClass. I would like to save lines of code by type parameterizing my test cases, meaning I would like to write the same test case and have C++ test the different types.

In my code I have made the following declaration:

```
template <Class T>
MyClass<T> CreateMyClass();


template <>
MyClass<Type1> CreateMyClass(){
  MyClass x;
  x.setSomething(..);
   ...
  return x;
}

template <>
  MyClass<Type2> CreateMyClass(){
  MyClass x;
  x.setSomething(..);
   ...
  return x;
}

#if GTEST_HAS_TYPED_TEST

typedef ::testing::Types<Type1, Type2> Implementations;  

TYPED_TEST_CASE(MyUnitTest, Implementations);
  template <class T>
  class MyUnitTest: public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
    MyUnitTest() : x(CreateMyClass<T>(){}

  virtual void SetUp() {
}

  virtual void TearDown() {
  // Code here will be called immediately after each test
  // (right before the destructor).
}

  MyClass<T> x;
}

TYPED_TEST(MyUnitTest, test1){
   MyObject<TypeParam> x1(this->x);
   MyObject<TypeParam> x2(this->x);

   EXPECT_EQ(x1,x2);
}
#endif
```

Everything works fine for Type1, but when the second test case is ran with Type2, the x object returned from CreateMyClass is set to null (found through debugging).

On visual studio I get an SEH exception and a Segmentation fault on Linux.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to provide "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example" see http://sscce.org/. Your code looks correct - probably the problem is in some area you did  not present... E.g. What are `MyObject` and `CreateCiphertext`?

Comment: I changed CreateCiphertext to CreateMyClass<T>. It would be very complicated to explain it all, but in short, MyObject is a templated class that can take in Type1 or Type2 as types which I forgot to add to the code above (adding now).

Comment: The problem is most probably in the code that is absent in your example.

Comment: I added missed construction - and everything works ok - see this http://pastebin.com/U4EMahb4